# iOS objective c parse query issue I can't seem to figure out why its not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Okay. I am picking up this work from someone else and its hard to understand.
so lets say I am making an app that keeps track of visitors coming into a building. 
What needs to determine is whether they are a current visitor or not, is the `timestamp`. If there is `timeOut` on parse is set to nil then they are still in the building. What logs the visitor out of the list is when the `timestamp` changes form nil to the current time. 
I want a way to log all visitors out if they have forgotten to sign out.
with on button click, I should be able to log all visitors on a `tableview` list called `current visitors`. the button will look for all visitors in the parse class with the `timeOut = nil`, and will then create a current `timestamp` for all those nils, refreshing the table to show that they are all gone. 
Here is what I have written so far. When the button is clicked, nothing happens.

```
- (IBAction)visitorLogOut:(UIButton *)sender {

if (![namesLabel.text isEqualToString:@"name"]){
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"VisitorTest"];
    [query fromLocalDatastore];
    [query whereKey:@"timeOut" equalTo:@"nil"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *visitors, NSError *error){

        NSDateFormatter *dformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dformat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];

        NSDate *time = [NSDate date];
        NSString *timeString = [dformat stringFromDate:time];

        self.person[@"timeOut"] = timeString;
        [self.person saveEventually];
        [self.person unpinInBackground];

    }

     ];}
```

}

Any help would be great. cheers!

Comment: Should timeOut contain the string "nil" or be actually nil? You're searching for records that have timeOut set to the *string* "nil", which is probably not what you want. You probably need to use `whereKeyDoesNotExist:` instead of `whereKey:equalTo:`.

Comment: @jcaron great answer, thank you. should i put anything after whereKeyDoesNotExist:?

Comment: The key you want to check, `@"timeout"`

Comment: @jcaron okay. still nothing unfortunately that way. ive added in `[query whereKey:@"name" equalTo:[[namesLabel.text lowercaseString] capitalizedString]];` to before that line. but now it breaks, "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: (null)'"

Comment: I have no idea from your code and description what namesLabel.text should contain or how it is related to what you're trying to achieve. I was under the impression that you wanted to match all users with a nil timeOut. Also, once PFQuery returns visitors, you should actually modify each one of those in turn and then save them.

Comment: @jcaron name of the visitor is coming from parse, and being filled into that label. i don't know why i need it either. i just want a button that will update all timeOut with nil to the current time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? First time around, it'll just show you the list of objects it received from the server. If that looks like what you want, you can then remove the `return;` and on next run it should set timeOut on all objects.

```
- (IBAction)visitorLogOut:(UIButton *)sender
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"VisitorTest"];
    [query fromLocalDatastore];
    [query whereKeyDoesNotExist:@"timeOut"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *visitors, NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"received visitors: %@");
        // remove this once you have confirmed that visitors contains exactly the users you want
        return;

        NSDateFormatter *dformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dformat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
        NSDate *time = [NSDate date];
        NSString *timeString = [dformat stringFromDate:time];

        for (PFObject *visitor in visitors)
        {
            visitor[@"timeOut"] = timeString;
            [visitor saveEventually];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this has lead me to getting it to work now! thank you!! especially using `whereKeyDoesNotExist:` helped.